# How i can test firestore?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, mockito

I try to test my `userService`.  To do this I prepared mock `FirebaseFirestore` and normal object `userService` with `firebaseFirestore` by constructor. When I run test my object `firebaseFirestore` have every fields as `null`. As I know I can't use in tests `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`. How I can test this?

```
@LargeTest
class UserServiceTest {

@Mock
private lateinit var firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var userService: UserService

constructor() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    userService = UserService(firebaseFirestore)
}

@Test
fun getUserByLogin() {
    Mockito.`when`(userService.getUserById("id", 1)).thenReturn(User())
}
```

}

```
class UserService {

 private val DATABASE_BANKOK: FirebaseFirestore 

 constructor(databaseInstance: FirebaseFirestore) {
    DATABASE_BANKOK = databaseInstance
 }

 fun getUserByLogin(fieldName: String, login: String): User {
    var user = User()
    DATABASE_BANKOK.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
        .whereEqualTo(fieldName, login)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            if (result.isEmpty) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User doesn't exist")
            }
            for (document in result) {
                user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
                Log.i(TAG, "Result from database: {$user}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting documents. Details: /n 
        {${exception.stackTrace}")
        }
    return user
}
```

}

Comment: It's a different solution than you asked, but mocking is easier if you make it clean architecture.
If you are not familiar with constructing such architecture, start by separating it with an interface.

Comment: As a concrete example, create an interface that surrounds your `FirebaseFirestore` and create a class implementation that uses `FirebaseFirestore` directly.
And then, you can simply mock this interface rather than mocking FirebaseFirestore.